# redirect with primary key django {% url %}

Tags: django, django-templates, django-cms

I want make blog where I have categories and posts inside.
 Categories should be displayed, and when you click on it, you are redirected to    another site where articles of this category are shown.

models.py:

```
class Category(CMSPlugin):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='category')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class Blog_post(CMSPlugin):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    style = models.ForeignKey(Blog_style)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='title')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='description')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static', null=True, blank=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
def Blog_list(request):
    posts = Blog_post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    category = Category.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blogspot.html', {'posts': posts, 'category':category})

def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Blog_post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'post_detail.html', {'post': post})

def category_detail(request, pk):
    cat = get_object_or_404(Category, id=pk)
    post_with_category = Blog_post.objects.filter(category=cat)
    return render(request, 'articles.html', {'post_with_category': post_with_category})
```

blogspot.html

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <h1><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{post.title}}</a></h1>
     <a href="{% url 'category_detail' pk=post.category.id %}" >{{ post.category }}</a>
    {{post.title}}
    {{ post.description }}
    {{ post.image }}
    {{ post.text }}{{ post.published_date }}
{% endfor %}
```

So far works all ok. I can click on {{post.title}} and im redirected to post_detail. Now i want to make same logic with categories. When i click on {{post.category}} i want redirect to articles.html where u can see all articles in specific category.

EDIT:

I inserted code to show posts in categories. I stucked with for loop. If i use loop mentioned in post, I get all posts and categories. The problem is if i have 2 posts in one category and this loop will show 2x "category" in template.

So I edited my for loop.

```
{% for post in category %}
        {{post.title}}
        {% endfor %}
```

If I insert  `<a href="{% url 'category_detail' pk=post.category.id %}" >{{post.title}}` in this loop i get no reverse match.
I tried to modify views.py category_detail

And url should looks like `localhost/<category>/`
And another question is, what is QRM alternative comand for `"select*from Table Where Column_id= id ;`

urls.py

```
 url(r'^blog/$', views.Blog_list, name='Blog_list'),
    url(r'^blog/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
```

Comment: What is the reasoning behind including `category = Category.objects.all()` in your Blog_list view?

Comment: I get printed all categories in template. If i use "post" loop i get printed categories as many posts i have. If i have 5 posts in category1. My loop prints 5 times category1

Comment: You are printing all of the categories in every Post template?

Comment: if i use {% for post in posts %}
     <a href="{% url 'category_detail' pk=post.category.id %}" >{{ post.category }}</a> {% endfor %} I get printed 5 categories, if i use category for loop i get printed categories.With "category" i get wanted result in rendered template

Comment: So, is your question is answered?  Or are you still facing issues?

Comment: @Doug honostly im still facing issuess.But it would be unfair to not mark your post as answer.. Im still having problems with categories. How can i use category_detail(your post) in {% for post in category %}
        {{post.title}}
        {% endfor %}

Comment: If you want to share more of your program (the update views and urls and also your templates), I'd be happy to look them over.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your question, django allows you to reference FK objects through the main object.  So, since your `post.category` is an instance of your `Category` model, you should be able to use `post.category.id` to do a reverse lookup, so your template would have something along the lines of:

```
<a href="{% url 'category_detail' pk=post.category.id %}" >{{ post.category }}</a>
```

Then, in your `category_detail` view you would just use the `pk` to get the lookup:

```
cat = get_object_or_404(Category, id=pk)
post_with_category = Blog_post.objects.filter(category=cat)
```

Then you could display the list of posts on the new url link that have the same category, via your new `post_with_category` object list.

EDIT:

Your urls would want to include something like the following for the above html href tag to work:

```
url(r'^cat/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.category_detail, name='category_detail'),
```

Comment: Thanks for help it works. Can you help me with url, i get numbers. How can I achieve to have names of categorys in urls?

Comment: If i have 2 titles in category2 , the name "category" is printed twice, because is "post in posts". how can i solve this?  I this teory if i have five posts i will get category2 printed 5 times in template

Comment: This code shows all of the posts with the same category as the original post, unless you are listing the category on `articles.html` it shouldn't list duplicates.  From your Category model, it doesn't look like you are supporting having 2 titles in one category...?

Comment: look Edited loop for post in category, if If i insert <a href="{% url 'category_detail' pk=post.category.id %}" >{{ post.category }}</a> I get an error for no reverse match

Comment: Did you add the url with the 'category_detail' name?  If Django can't find the url name in your href, it will fail the reverse lookup, which is what it sounds like is happening here.